# R read.xlsx comment character option

Tags: r, import

I am using the `read.xlsx` function from the `openxlsx` package. Simply, I was wondering if there is any work around to identify comment headers within sheets.

For example if the sheet look liked

```
# information about data
ID    Value
A    10
B    3
C    19
```

I want to be able to use `read.xlsx` in a similar way I use `read.delim` for .txt files and used the `comment.char = "#"` option however that does not exist for read.xlsx.

```
## ideal code    
df <- read.xlsx("data.xlsx", sheet = 1, comment.char = "#")
```

I can obviously use the `startRow` option, but this requires me to manually look at each sheet and determine how many commented lines there are.

My thoughts for a workaround are to some how look into the sheets and return the number of lines that contain # at the start and pass this variable to the `startRow` option. Any ideas on how/if this is possible? Or any other functions/options that I have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your own wrapper function for read.xlsx that handles this case, like this...

This assume Book1.xlsx contains your example data in the first sheet.

```
library(openxlsx)

wb_file <- "Book1.xlsx"

wb <- loadWorkbook(wb_file)

#custom function to skip header comment rows
read.xlsx.skip.comment <- function(wb, comment.char = "#", ...){

  #read data from sheet 1
  shx <- read.xlsx(wb, ...)

  #count comment rows
  skip.rows <- grep(paste0("^", comment.char), c(names(shx)[1], shx[ , 1]))

  #skip comment header rows if they exist
  if(length(skip.rows) > 0) shx <- read.xlsx(wb, startRow = max(skip.rows) + 1, ...)

  return(shx)
}

#call the function, use default comment.char
foo <- read.xlsx.skip.comment(wb = wb, sheet = 1)
```

Note that `...` allows to specify other read.xlsx parameters (e.g., sheet).

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
mydat1 <- read.table('C:\\my_path\\file.txt', comment.char = '', header = FALSE)
mydat1
```

Let's say following is our test Input_file:

```
##1
12
123
1234
```

Without setting `comment.char = ''` output will be as follows:

```
mydat1 <- read.table('C:\\my_path_test\\file.txt', header = FALSE)
mydat1
> mydat1
    V1
1   12
2  123
3 1234
```

BY Setting comment.char to NULL following will the output(***which is required by OP***).

```
mydat1 <- read.table('C:\\my_path_test\\file.txt', comment.char = '', header = FALSE)
mydat1
> mydat1
    V1
1  ##1
2   12
3  123
4 1234
```

Comment: The issue isn't for a txt file but rather a excel file (.xlsx) and the sheets within that spreadsheet. The `read.xlsx` function doesn't consider # a comment character and there is no option in that function (that I saw) that can pass that information in